# Java JSON output double }} at the end

Tags: java, json

Hi am trying to create a huge json for some reason it keeps adding the double brackets at the end i can't seem to see why its doing that i don't see anything wrong with the code

```
private static void DoLogin(UserData user) {
    JSONObject UData = new JSONObject();
    UData.put("name", user.CharName);
    UData.put("intAccessLevel", 0);
    UData.put("bitFounder", JSONObject.NULL);
    UData.put("element", 1);
    UData.put("idPlayer", user.UserId);
    UData.put("intGold", user.Gold);
    UData.put("intGem", user.Gem);
    UData.put("intGemLifetime", JSONObject.NULL);
    UData.put("intAlignment", 0);
    UData.put("intAP", 0);
    UData.put("intBlock", 0);
    UData.put("intChaos", 0);
    UData.put("intCriticalHit" , 0);
    UData.put("intDP", 0);
    UData.put("intEarth", 0);
    UData.put("intEnergy", 0);
    UData.put("intFire", 0);
    UData.put("intHits", 0);
    UData.put("intHometown" , 1);
    UData.put("intIce", 0);
    UData.put("intInitiative", 0);
    UData.put("intLuck", 0);
    UData.put("intNeutral", 0);
    UData.put("intPower" ,0);
    UData.put("intStamina", 0);
    UData.put("intShadow", 0);
    UData.put("intWater", 0);
    UData.put("dateDOB", "1/1/1987");
    UData.put("dateMuteUntil", JSONObject.NULL);

    if (user.CharactersID.split(",").length > 0) {
        JSONArray CharactersArray = new JSONArray();
        JSONArray CharInven = new JSONArray();

        for (String id : user.CharactersID.split(",")) {
            if (DBGet.CharacterList.containsKey(Integer.parseInt(id))) {

                CharactersArray.put(Getter.GetCharacterData(DBGet.CharacterList.get(Integer.parseInt(id))));
                Characters character = DBGet.CharacterList.get(Integer.parseInt(id));

                JSONObject charInvenData = new JSONObject();
                charInvenData.put("idAdjPlayerCharacter", character.Id);
                charInvenData.put("idPlayer", user.UserId);
                charInvenData.put("idCharacter", character.Id);
                charInvenData.put("intUnlocked", 1);
                charInvenData.put("intLevel", character.Level);
                charInvenData.put("intExp", 0);

                if (user.CharID == character.Id) {
                    charInvenData.put("bDefault", true);
                } else {
                    charInvenData.put("bDefault", false);
                }

                CharInven.put(charInvenData);
            }
        }
        JSONObject cmd = new JSONObject();
        cmd.put("status", 1);
        cmd.put("type", "login");
        cmd.put("player", UData);
        cmd.put("characters", CharactersArray);
        cmd.put("charInventory", CharInven);
        cmd.put("items", new JSONArray());
        cmd.put("itemInventory", new JSONArray());
        cmd.put("cards", JSONObject.NULL);
        cmd.put("cardInventory", JSONObject.NULL);
        user.SendPacket(cmd.toString());
    }
}
```

What Getter.GetCharacterData Is:

```
public static JSONObject GetCharacterData(Characters Character) {

    JSONObject characterData = new JSONObject();
                characterData.put("idCharacter",Character.Id);
                characterData.put("strName", Character.Name);
                characterData.put("idCharacterType", Character.CharacterType);
                characterData.put("idCharacterPrereq", Character.CharacterPrereq);
                characterData.put("idCharacterOwner", Character.Id);
                characterData.put("idItemPrereq", Character.ItemPrereq);
                characterData.put("strFilename", Character.Filename);
                characterData.put("strAttach", Character.Attach);
                characterData.put("idElement", Character.Element);
                characterData.put("intCaptureRate", Character.CaptureRate);
                characterData.put("intCost", Character.Cost);
                characterData.put("intLevel", Character.Level);
                characterData.put("intAlignment", JSONObject.NULL);
                characterData.put("intStoreGold", JSONObject.NULL);
                characterData.put("intStoreGem", JSONObject.NULL);
                characterData.put("bSellable", JSONObject.NULL);
            return characterData;

}
```

I need the json result to be:

```
{
"status": 1,
"type": "login",
"player": {
    "name": "What",
    "intAccessLevel": 0,
    "bitFounder": null,
    "element": 1,
    "idPlayer": 4,
    "intGold": 0,
    "intGem": 0,
    "intGemLifetime": null,
    "intAlignment": 0,
    "intAP": 0,
    "intBlock": 0,
    "intChaos": 0,
    "intCriticalHit": 0,
    "intDP": 0,
    "intEarth": 0,
    "intEnergy": 0,
    "intFire": 0,
    "intHits": 0,
    "intHometown": 1,
    "intIce": 0,
    "intInitiative": 0,
    "intLuck": 0,
    "intNeutral": 0,
    "intPower": 0,
    "intStamina": 0,
    "intShadow": 0,
    "intWater": 0,
    "dateDOB": "1/1/1987",
    "dateMuteUntil": null
},
"characters": [
    {
        "idCharacter": 264,
        "strName": "Infernal Fiend",
        "idCharacterType": 3,
        "idCharacterPrereq": -1,
        "idCharacterOwner": 264,
        "idItemPrereq": -1,
        "strFilename": "InfernalFiendSwords1-Fire-E-M-Master1",
        "strAttach": -1,
        "idElement": 1,
        "intCaptureRate": 25,
        "intCost": 0,
        "intLevel": 9,
        "intAlignment": null,
        "intStoreGold": null,
        "intStoreGem": null,
        "bSellable": null
    },
    {
        "idCharacter": 4,
        "strName": "Void of Nulgath",
        "idCharacterType": 1,
        "idCharacterPrereq": -1,
        "idCharacterOwner": 4,
        "idItemPrereq": -1,
        "strFilename": "0VoidKnightArmblades1-Shadow-N-M-Starter1-opt",
        "strAttach": -1,
        "idElement": 7,
        "intCaptureRate": 50,
        "intCost": 0,
        "intLevel": 0,
        "intAlignment": null,
        "intStoreGold": null,
        "intStoreGem": null,
        "bSellable": null
    },
    {
        "idCharacter": 5,
        "strName": "Wolf",
        "idCharacterType": 1,
        "idCharacterPrereq": -1,
        "idCharacterOwner": 5,
        "idItemPrereq": -1,
        "strFilename": "0Wolf1-Lighting-N-M-Starter1-opt",
        "strAttach": -1,
        "idElement": 3,
        "intCaptureRate": 50,
        "intCost": 0,
        "intLevel": 0,
        "intAlignment": null,
        "intStoreGold": null,
        "intStoreGem": null,
        "bSellable": null
    }
],
"charInventory": [
    {
        "idAdjPlayerCharacter": 264,
        "idPlayer": 4,
        "idCharacter": 264,
        "intUnlocked": 1,
        "intLevel": 9,
        "intExp": 0,
        "bDefault": false
    },
    {
        "idAdjPlayerCharacter": 4,
        "idPlayer": 4,
        "idCharacter": 4,
        "intUnlocked": 1,
        "intLevel": 0,
        "intExp": 0,
        "bDefault": false
    },
    {
        "idAdjPlayerCharacter": 5,
        "idPlayer": 4,
        "idCharacter": 5,
        "intUnlocked": 1,
        "intLevel": 0,
        "intExp": 0,
        "bDefault": true
    }
],
"items": [],
"itemInventory": [],
"cards": null,
"cardInventory": null
}
```

What my code returns:

```
{
"characters": [
    {
        "idElement": 1,
        "idCharacter": 264,
        "strAttach": -1,
        "intLevel": 9,
        "intAlignment": null,
        "intStoreGem": null,
        "strFilename": "InfernalFiendSwords1-Fire-E-M-Master1",
        "idItemPrereq": -1,
        "intCaptureRate": 25,
        "strName": "Infernal Fiend",
        "idCharacterType": 3,
        "intCost": 0,
        "bSellable": null,
        "idCharacterOwner": 264,
        "intStoreGold": null,
        "idCharacterPrereq": -1
    },
    {
        "idElement": 7,
        "idCharacter": 4,
        "strAttach": -1,
        "intLevel": 0,
        "intAlignment": null,
        "intStoreGem": null,
        "strFilename": "0VoidKnightArmblades1-Shadow-N-M-Starter1-opt",
        "idItemPrereq": -1,
        "intCaptureRate": 50,
        "strName": "Void of Nulgath",
        "idCharacterType": 1,
        "intCost": 0,
        "bSellable": null,
        "idCharacterOwner": 4,
        "intStoreGold": null,
        "idCharacterPrereq": -1
    },
    {
        "idElement": 3,
        "idCharacter": 5,
        "strAttach": -1,
        "intLevel": 0,
        "intAlignment": null,
        "intStoreGem": null,
        "strFilename": "0Wolf1-Lighting-N-M-Starter1-opt",
        "idItemPrereq": -1,
        "intCaptureRate": 50,
        "strName": "Wolf",
        "idCharacterType": 1,
        "intCost": 0,
        "bSellable": null,
        "idCharacterOwner": 5,
        "intStoreGold": null,
        "idCharacterPrereq": -1
    }
],
"charInventory": [
    {
        "bDefault": false,
        "idPlayer": 4,
        "idCharacter": 264,
        "intUnlocked": 1,
        "idAdjPlayerCharacter": 264,
        "intLevel": 9,
        "intExp": 0
    },
    {
        "bDefault": false,
        "idPlayer": 4,
        "idCharacter": 4,
        "intUnlocked": 1,
        "idAdjPlayerCharacter": 4,
        "intLevel": 0,
        "intExp": 0
    },
    {
        "bDefault": true,
        "idPlayer": 4,
        "idCharacter": 5,
        "intUnlocked": 1,
        "idAdjPlayerCharacter": 5,
        "intLevel": 0,
        "intExp": 0
    }
],
"cards": null,
"itemInventory": [],
"cardInventory": null,
"type": "login",
"items": [],
"status": 1,
"player": {
    "intAccessLevel": 0,
    "intDP": 0,
    "intPower": 0,
    "intShadow": 0,
    "intGold": 0,
    "intChaos": 0,
    "intHometown": 1,
    "intAlignment": 0,
    "intGem": 0,
    "intBlock": 0,
    "dateMuteUntil": null,
    "intCriticalHit": 0,
    "intWater": 0,
    "bitFounder": null,
    "element": 1,
    "intGemLifetime": null,
    "intFire": 0,
    "intAP": 0,
    "intHits": 0,
    "intLuck": 0,
    "intIce": 0,
    "intEarth": 0,
    "intInitiative": 0,
    "intNeutral": 0,
    "dateDOB": "1/1/1987",
    "intStamina": 0,
    "idPlayer": 4,
    "intEnergy": 0,
    "name": "What"
}
}
```

Why is it doing that can anybody make a fix or try to help thank you very much.

Comment: to me both looks same except the ordering. checkout here http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: Can't you line wrap the JSON?  It is unreadable in its current form!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between your expectation and the output you have, except order of elements.

Comment: and the order of attributes inside a JSON-Object does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

The first "}" is for the object player. I think your JSON is correct!

Comment: Thank you for your time.